# package 'com.example.myapp' already exists in this project in folder 'gen' in Eclipse

Tags: android

I have tried to refactor my Android project package by right clicking on the project folder > ***Android Tools*** > ***Rename Application Package***. But it only refactored the package in `gen` folder.

Now I am trying to refactor the package in `src` folder as well using `alt+shift+R` shortcut, it gives me the following problem:

[image]

Why this problem happens and what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Wouldn't it cause any conflicts in my app if I did so?

Comment: Yes,It will update your package name